# Symfony firewall access_control doesn't work if no firewall match

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I have a problem with **symfony** firewalls...
Here an example:

```
app_customer_provider:
      security: true
       lazy: true
       stateless person: true
        custom_authenticators:
             - XXX\Authenticator
             - XXX\Authenticator
         request_matcher: - XXX\Mathcer
```

In the access control *access_control* I have a protected route, ex */ping*.

When I try to login with a JWT that matches the *request_matcher*, the authenticator works fine; blocking or allow access to the various routes.

The problem arises when no *request_matcher* intervenes. All routes are open despite being role protected, ex */ping* is accessible.

Can you help me about it? Is there something I’m doing wrong or I’m missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a symfony behavior...
If no firewall is hitted, the *security_access* is not considered.

I use this workaround, use a fallback firewall in this way :

```
secured_area:
   pattern: ^/
```